# How to customize model in Springfox's Swagger 2 for a string request body?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I would like to customize the model for my API documentation I am making with Springfox's Swagger (Spring REST API).

[image]

This is an example for my code:

```
   @ApiOperation("Creating a kafka topic")
   @ApiImplicitParams(
           @ApiImplicitParam(name = "requestBody", value = "The body of request", required = true,
                   example = "{\"server\": \"localhost:9092\",\"topic\": \"test\", \"parmas\":{...}}")
   )
   public ResponseEntity<String> createTopic(@RequestBody String requestBody) {
       TopicCreationRequest request = gson.fromJson(requestBody, TopicCreationRequest.class);

       ...

       return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response.toString());
   }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not create a POJO of the request body? Although it seems like you do ? `TopicCreationRequest`? Why not use it as the Param instead of String?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas__ I switched POJO and it work